# Enemy will deal damage when testing in scene but not in the build, any insight?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am creating a horror game in unity about a creature in a forest that stalks you while you traverse the forest. While testing in unity the stalker will deal damage but when im building and running it does not deal damage when attacking. Does anyone have any insight?

I've edited the code to make it creepier to keep a player from noticing the lack of damage however i have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: check the console in the build for errors.

Comment: `Does anyone have any insight?` .. we don't have your code/project => No, of course we do not have any insight.

Comment: What @derHugo said. It's literally impossible to know where the issue lies when you've given us nothing but the symptoms. There are thousands of possible causes for these symptoms, to just start guessing would be madness. Please help us help you by sharing your code and maybe other relevant project settings.

Comment: When you run a program from Visual Studio, the working directory is usually set to the project directory, not the bin/debug/net8.0 directory.

You can add debugging statements to your code to ensure that the damage handling code executes as expected. For example, you could add Debug.Log("Dealing Damage!"); to see if the code reaches that point before the damage is calculated.